# MySql how to use UPDATE with HAVING?

Tags: mysql, sql

My `table1` looks like:

```
id  name_co  name_r  temp  sld
 1   name1     1      ...  ...
 2   name2     1      ...  ...
 3   name2     1      ...  ...
 4   name2     1      ...  ...
 5   name3     1      ...  ...
 6   name2     1      ...  ...
```

I need to increment `name_r` if there are two or more identical `name_co`.
To be so:

```
     
id  name_co  name_r  temp  sld
 1   name1     1      ...  ...
 2   name2     1      ...  ...
 3   name2     2      ...  ...
 4   name2     3      ...  ...
 5   name3     1      ...  ...
 6   name2     4      ...  ...
```

I tried different options and I came to this:

```
    UPDATE table1 
        SET name_r = name_r + 1 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        GROUP BY name_co 
        HAVING name_co > 1)
```

The query works and returns 0 rows, but I know that in some way he's wrong, but I can't figure out what. Can anyone help? (And a bit of explanation, so I better understood)

Comment: The final two columns appear to have no relevance to the question, so I'm unclear why they're included above

Comment: I tried: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS test FROM table1 GROUP BY name_co HAVING test > 1` to combine with `UPDATE table1 SET name_r = name_r + 1`. For `UPDATE` to work with `HAVING`. I know that this query poorly drafted.

Comment: If you provide a sqlfiddle or rextester, I'm sure someone will supply a solution. But leave out the irrelevant columns

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will post correct for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--updated intended targets
UPDATE table1 
SET    name_r = name_r + 1 
WHERE  id IN 
(
    -- return those ids again (to avoid the mysql #1093 error)
    SELECT  id
    FROM
    (   -- get all the ids for those names
        SELECT  id
        FROM    table1
        WHERE   name_co IN
        (   -- get all names that have more than one id
            SELECT   name_co
            FROM     table1 
            GROUP BY name_co 
            HAVING   COUNT(id) > 1
        )
    ) a
)
```

Comment: This query returns: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: This one returns: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`. So I tried this: `UPDATE table1
SET name_r = name_r + 1 
WHERE id IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT id
                    FROM table1 AS alia
                    GROUP BY id, name_co 
                    HAVING COUNT(name_co) > 1
                ) AS alias
            ) ` It works, but returns 0 rows.

Comment: Updated answer to include alias for subquery -- can you run the inner most subquery that has the COUNT clause... does that actually return any data for your specific data set?

Comment: saw initial query was incorrect, updated the query to correct query and included comments

Comment: hm mysql says: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax`

Comment: @AgentSmith fixed!

Comment: Anyone able to please comment on why the answer was downvoted? Thanks!

Comment: It works great! Thank you very much! Will be a lot of things to explore sampling variation request! But there are second my mistake, beside `name_co > 1`. The request updated rows name_co and `name_r`: `2,2,2,2`, instead of  `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Oh, because it's so long winded. Plus it was wrong, but maybe that's fixed now.

Comment: At this time I don't know how to build sql query, that will add i++. I'll think about it and perhaps I'll use php.