# DUPLICATE KEY with auto add +1 to the cell?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, For example: http://rextester.com/MVG66914

User fills in the fields: `name_1`(fill any text) and `name_2`(fill 1 or nothing).
If the cell `name_1` contains the same text - `name_2`cell should be increased by 1.

To look like this: http://rextester.com/FSI28573

I can't set `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY`. You can see it on the table examples.

But I can set `INDEX` Maybe like this:

`` ALTER TABLE `table15` ADD INDEX(`name_1`); ``

`` ALTER TABLE `table15` ADD INDEX(`name_2`); ``

For example:

`INSERT INTO table14a (id, name_1, name_2) VALUES (2, name_1, name_2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name_2=name_2+1;`

http://rextester.com/YJZ25085

But it should need to be increased by 1 automatically, every time, when user creates a new row with identical text in `name_1`

`INSERT INTO productsfp (?) VALUES (?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name_2=name_2+1;`

So I tried a variations with `DUPLICATE KEY` But it didn't work.

I asked question: [MySql how to use UPDATE with HAVING?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261038/mysql-how-to-use-update-with-having][1])
But I realized that I was mistaken in forming request. Cuz all values increases by 1, instead of a serial. Then I read MySql documentation about `DUPLICATE KEY` and are now stuck in a given issue. Does anyone know how to solve this query?

Comment: you can use a trigger before insertion of data into the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a composite key involving `name_1` and `id`, then `id` will auto increment within each name group.  The following table definition would achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table15` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name_1` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(`name_1`, `id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Note that this won't work with InnoDB, but it will work with MyISAM.  Also, I removed the `name_2` column, because now the `id` column will track what you intended for `name_2`.

Further reading: [auto_increment by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677542/auto-increment-by-group)

**Update:**

If you still want a continuous, linear, auto increment ID column, then you can compute it while selecting using the following scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE `table15` (
    `name_2` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name_1` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`name_id`, `name_2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SELECT t1.name_2,
       t1.name_id,
       t1.name_1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table15 t2
        WHERE t2.name_id < t1.name_id) + t1.name_2 AS id
FROM table15 t1
```

This assumes that your table would contain a `name_id` column, which contains integer identifiers for each unique name which appears.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Yeah, this work: http://rextester.com/JPNIBC73499
But what can I do, if I need `id` cell. I tried several variations, but they did'nt work, I need to consider more deeply.

Comment: You could compute the `id` value while querying, if you use a numerical `name_id` instead of the text name as the prefix to the primary key.

Comment: Very close to what I want to do. I experimented, but it wasn't possible to do such as: `1,2,3,4,5,6 -> Dan, Mike, Mike, Mike, Peter, Peter - 1,1,2,3,1,2`. It didn't get correctly to associate `id` with `name_id`

Comment: `but it wasn't possible` ... well what actually happened?  Your comment doesn't tell us this.

Comment: `name_id` is AI and and will introduce the calculation based on the same fields in `name_1`. Ok, it's perfect, I understand how this works. But for example, I have a drop-down list in which I want to select any line, and I don't have a unique field, the type of standard `id ai`, that will count 1,2,3,...8,9,10... By your example I have is greater than equate field doesn't go. http://imgur.com/a/LDPx7

Comment: Yes, I think the equation will still work, because we always add on the `name_2` incremented value, which can never be smaller than 1.  So, if only one group in the drop down, then you would get `1,2,3,...`.

Comment: So that's I mean about I get `1,2,3,4...` or `1,1,2,3...` And all I want to do to make `1,2,3,4...` and `1,1,2,3...` `name_id` returns 0 in every row. And `name_2` or `1,2,3,4...` or `1,1,2,3...`

Comment: NO... _you_ assign the `name_id` in your original data set.  The point is that you give a unique integer id to every name, that's all.

Comment: Oh... Something didn't understand, I'll do an hour break and reconsider all of what you and I were talking and tell

Comment: I tried a variety of options with `name_id`, doesn't want to work together to make it as here: http://rextester.com/FSI28573